# Dynamic OpenCV Histogram errors

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am using a variant the Histogram comparison code given by the OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html) to check the similarities of a submitted image to others stored in my filesystem. The problem is that the values I am getting are different from the original comparison that I used.

Original code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat src_base, hsv_base;
  Mat src_test1, hsv_test1;
  Mat src_test2, hsv_test2;
  Mat hsv_half_down;

  /// Load three images with different environment settings
  if( argc < 4 )
    { printf("** Error. Usage: ./compareHist_Demo <image_settings0> <image_setting1> <image_settings2>\n");
      return -1;
    }

  src_base = imread( argv[1], 1 );
  src_test1 = imread( argv[2], 1 );
  src_test2 = imread( argv[3], 1 );

  /// Convert to HSV
  cvtColor( src_base, hsv_base, CV_BGR2HSV );
  cvtColor( src_test1, hsv_test1, CV_BGR2HSV );
  cvtColor( src_test2, hsv_test2, CV_BGR2HSV );

  hsv_half_down = hsv_base( Range( hsv_base.rows/2, hsv_base.rows - 1 ), Range( 0, hsv_base.cols - 1 ) );

  /// Using 30 bins for hue and 32 for saturation
  int h_bins = 50; int s_bins = 60;
  int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins };

  // hue varies from 0 to 256, saturation from 0 to 180
  float h_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };
  float s_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };

  const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges };

  // Use the o-th and 1-st channels
  int channels[] = { 0, 1 };

  /// Histograms
  MatND hist_base;
  MatND hist_half_down;
  MatND hist_test1;
  MatND hist_test2;

  /// Calculate the histograms for the HSV images
  calcHist( &hsv_base, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_base, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
  normalize( hist_base, hist_base, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  calcHist( &hsv_half_down, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_half_down, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
  normalize( hist_half_down, hist_half_down, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  calcHist( &hsv_test1, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_test1, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
  normalize( hist_test1, hist_test1, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  calcHist( &hsv_test2, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_test2, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
  normalize( hist_test2, hist_test2, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  /// Apply the histogram comparison methods
  for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
     { int compare_method = i;
       double base_base = compareHist( hist_base, hist_base, compare_method );
       double base_half = compareHist( hist_base, hist_half_down, compare_method );
       double base_test1 = compareHist( hist_base, hist_test1, compare_method );
       double base_test2 = compareHist( hist_base, hist_test2, compare_method );

       printf( " Method [%d] Perfect, Base-Half, Base-Test(1), Base-Test(2) : %f, %f, %f, %f \n", i, base_base, base_half , base_test1, base_test2 );
     }

  printf( "Done \n" );

  return 0;
 }
```

Heres how I have changed the code (I carry on from the second calcHist):

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;    

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat src_base, hsv_base;
    Mat hsv_half_down;
    Mat src_rest, hsv_rest;

    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        printf("** Error. Usage: ./compareHist_Demo <image_settings0> <image_setting1> <image_settings2>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    src_base = imread( argv[1], 1 );

    /// Convert to HSV
    cvtColor( src_base, hsv_base, COLOR_BGR2HSV );
    hsv_half_down = hsv_base( Range( hsv_base.rows/2, hsv_base.rows - 1 ), Range( 0, hsv_base.cols - 1 ) );

    /// Using 30 bins for hue and 32 for saturation
    int h_bins = 50; int s_bins = 60;
    int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins };

    // hue varies from 0 to 256, saturation from 0 to 180
    float s_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };
    float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };

    const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges };

    // Use the o-th and 1-st channels
    int channels[] = { 0, 1 };


    /// Histograms
    MatND hist_base;
    MatND hist_half_down;
    MatND hist_rest;

    /// Calculate the histograms for the HSV images
    calcHist( &hsv_base, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_base, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
    normalize( hist_base, hist_base, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    calcHist( &hsv_half_down, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_half_down, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
    normalize( hist_half_down, hist_half_down, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
Mat src_rest, hsv_rest;
MatND hist_rest;
std::vector<string> src;

    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("/Users/Dave/Desktop/foods.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            src.push_back(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    long arrLength = src.size();

    for(int i = 0;i<arrLength;i++){

        src_rest = imread(src[i],1);
        cvtColor(src_rest, hsv_rest, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        calcHist(&hsv_rest, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_rest, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false);
        normalize(hist_rest, hist_rest, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());
        double baseComp = compareHist( hist_rest, hist_base, 0 );
        cout<<"Main picture compared to "<<src[i]<<" using correlation "<<baseComp<<'\n';
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(int i = 0;i<arrLength;i++){

        src_rest = imread(src[i],1);
        cvtColor(src_rest, hsv_rest, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        calcHist(&hsv_rest, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_rest, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false);
        normalize(hist_rest, hist_rest, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());
        double baseComp = compareHist( hist_rest, hist_base, 1 );
        cout<<"Main picture compared to "<<src[i]<<" using chi values "<<baseComp<<'\n';
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<arrLength;i++){

        src_rest = imread(src[i],1);
        cvtColor(src_rest, hsv_rest, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        calcHist(&hsv_rest, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_rest, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false);
        normalize(hist_rest, hist_rest, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());
        double baseComp = compareHist( hist_rest, hist_base, 2 );
        cout<<"Main picture compared to "<<src[i]<<" intersection "<<baseComp<<'\n';
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<arrLength;i++){

        src_rest = imread(src[i],1);
        cvtColor(src_rest, hsv_rest, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        calcHist(&hsv_rest, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_rest, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false);
        normalize(hist_rest, hist_rest, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());
        double baseComp = compareHist( hist_base, hist_rest, 3 );
        cout<<"Main picture compared to "<<src[i]<<" bhattacharyya "<<baseComp<<'\n';
    }
```

The rest of code that has been omitted is the rest of the initialisation in the OpenCV version.

Heres the original output:

```
 Method [0] Perfect, Base-Half, Base-Test(1), Base-Test(2) : 1.000000, 0.999990, 0.979741, 0.952336 
 Method [1] Perfect, Base-Half, Base-Test(1), Base-Test(2) : 0.000000, 0.018286, 128.338021, 130.609857 
 Method [2] Perfect, Base-Half, Base-Test(1), Base-Test(2) : 1.260779, 1.225753, 1.225654, 1.254846 
 Method [3] Perfect, Base-Half, Base-Test(1), Base-Test(2) : 0.000000, 0.052663, 0.440655, 0.494793
```

And heres my output:

```
Main picture compared to base.jpg using correlation 1
Main picture compared to test1.jpg using correlation 0.763895
Main picture compared to test2.jpg using correlation 0.54124

Main picture compared to base.jpg using chi values 0
Main picture compared to test1.jpg using chi values 223.443
Main picture compared to test2.jpg using chi values 876.137

Main picture compared to base.jpg intersection 3.4481
Main picture compared to test1.jpg intersection 1.78523
Main picture compared to test2.jpg intersection 1.79021

Main picture compared to base.jpg bhattacharyya 1.05367e-08
Main picture compared to test1.jpg bhattacharyya 0.569303
Main picture compared to test2.jpg bhattacharyya 0.675118
```

So is there an issue with the way I have laid out the code in loops for me to get completely different results?

Comment: The question is a bit imprecise. What's your point? What do you think could be an issue here?

Comment: Sorry, whats unclear? I am trying to say why do I get 2 separate results from my code and the OpenCV code despite it being nearly identical but mine was done the comparison in a loop.

Comment: So are pic1, pic2 the same images as Half, Test1, Test2? Do you expect the same result values?

Comment: No pic1 is equivalent to Test1 and pic2 is to Test2. I chose not to use half in the second section.

Comment: channels, ranges and hist_base is the same in the second section?

Comment: Yes everything is completely the same, ill post the whole code.